# ArgumentError: invalid strptime format - `%m/%d/%y' work around

Tags: ruby, date, time, strptime

I am in the process of working with an sftp import bug in which I'm trying to flag any dates that are imported that are incorrect. There are two types of dates that could be off. The first is when the year is in the future, or way in the past; the second is when the actual months and days are too high. (Example, 13/20/1995, or 11/35/2000)

I'm using `strptime` and for dates that are off, flagging them and displaying them as a specific message.  The problem I'm running into is that with the `strptime` format that I'm using, the errors happen right before I sub in the error message.

```
table_birth_dates = self.class.connection.execute("SELECT birth_date FROM #{temp_table_name}").values.flatten

table_birth_dates.map! do |date|
  birth_date = Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')

  if birth_date.nil?
    month_day_error_message = 'Invalid Month/Day'
  elsif birth_date > Time.zone.today
    future_error_message = 'Year in Future'
  elsif birth_date.year < 1900
    past_error_message = 'Year too old'
  else
    birth_date
  end
end
```

The error is happening at the `birth_date = Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')`
For a date such as  `10/3/1891,` it displays them as `Sat, 03 Oct 1891.`
However, for the messed up dates such as `33/33/2000` it shows me an error (which makes sense) however I was hoping to fix this error in my conditional.

Would anyone know what I could do?

Comment: Might take a look at [`Date::valid_date?`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-valid_date-3F).

Comment: The easiest way is to rescue the exception. An in-line rescue would be `require 'date'; birth_date = Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y') rescue nil`, which sets `birth_date` to `nil` if `date` does not represent a valid date. You could use `Date::valid_date?`, as @orde suggested, but to do so you need to parse out the year, month and day: `month, day, year = "11/35/2000".scan(/\d+(?=\/|\z)/).map(&:to_i) #=> [4, 35, 2000]; Date.valid_date?(year, month, day) #=> false`. (In the regex, `(?=\/|\z)` is a positive lookahead. It may be sufficient for the regex to be simply `/\d+/`.)

Comment: Hey Thanks @CarySwoveland very helpful and easy way to work around the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `strptime` your only option really is to rescue the error:

```
begin
  birth_date = Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
rescue ArgumentError => ex
  raise ex unless ex.message == 'invalid date'
  # handle invalid date
end
```

You could set `date` to, e.g., `:invalid` there and then have `date == :invalid` in your conditional if you want to keep all the logic there instead of in the `rescue` itself.

Comment: I like how you use `ex`. Can we be confident that, in future, `'invalid date'` won't be changed to some other wording? More generally, do you know if Ruby guarantees that the string descriptions returned with argument classes will not change? I have always thought of the string as merely being helpful to coders, and have not seen it used in code, but using it as you have makes perfect sense.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, which is why one should write tests to assert it behaves as expected. If then a future Ruby version changes the message, the test will fail and the code may be adjusted as needed.

Comment: Good point, and even before testing, the `ArgumentError` exception will be raised, which also covers the possibility that the tests have missed this potential problem.  An alternative view is that an `ArgumentError` exception could only be raised when the string does not represent a valid date, in which case `rescue ArgumentError` would be sufficient, and one would not have to be concerned about `"invalid date'` changing.  Considering that this only involves a single, simple line of code, is that reasonable?

Comment: I've wondered why `strptime` (and other date/time methods) doesn't just return `nil` when the string does not represent a valid date. Do you or anyone else know why the Ruby monks decided it should instead raise an exception?

Comment: @CarySwoveland No idea (though some would say exceptions are better than copious `nil`s everywhere).