# Convert String to Date Object Ruby

Tags: ruby, logging, logstash

I'm trying to comvert a string in my logs to a date object.

My string is `2018-09-18 11:42:50,286000201` which is the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,nnnnnnnnn`
I'm trying to convert in to an object using the time library in ruby. The function I am using is `Time.strptime('2018-09-18 11:42:50,286000201, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%9N')`

Ruby is giving me an invalid striptime format. Any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArgumentError: invalid strptime format - \`%m/%d/%y' work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356736/argumenterror-invalid-strptime-format-m-d-y-work-around)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the `9`, `%N` expects 9 digits bt default

```
Time.strptime('2018-09-18 11:42:50,286000201, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%N')
```

doc: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime